# Function on an infinite loop? I want to return the value of the exponential base (2**3 which should return 8)?

Tags: infinite-loop, exponential

Why my function results in infinite loop? I want to return the value of the exponential base (2**3 which should return 8)?

`def iterPower(base, exp):`

```
    i = 0
    answer = 0
    while exp >= 0:
        if i!= exp:
            answer = base * (base * i)
            i += 1
        else:
            answer = base * (base * i)
    return answer

   iterPower(2,3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are stucked in the infinite loop because of `while` condition is comparing `exp` which is not decreasing

I simplified your code to:

```py
def iter_power(base, exp):
    answer = 1
    while exp > 0:
        answer *= base
        exp -= 1

    return answer


print(iter_power(2, 3))  # 8
print(iter_power(2, 0))  # 1
print(iter_power(2, 8))  # 256
```